# Java Regex to replace a character and empty lines

Tags: java, regex

I have the following input text:

```
"rd_tagged_text"
"    Amt<SPLIT>
\nSecurity<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> Px<SPLIT> A<SPLIT> Px<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> YTW<SPLIT> A<SPLIT> YTW<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> ZS<SPLIT> A<SPLIT> ZS<SPLIT> Out<SPLIT> S&am<SPLIT> Mood<SPLIT> Note<SPLIT>
\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------<SPLIT> 
\nAltice<SPLIT> France<SPLIT>
\nNUMFP<SPLIT> 4.875<SPLIT> 19<SPLIT> 99.875<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>100.375<SPLIT> 4.909<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>4.752<SPLIT> 371.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>371.<SPLIT> 2.4MMM<SPLIT> B+<SPLIT> Ba3<SPLIT>
\nNUMFP<SPLIT> 6<SPLIT> 22<SPLIT> 102.000<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>102.500<SPLIT> 5.559<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>5.450<SPLIT> 422.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>411.<SPLIT> 4MMM<SPLIT> B+<SPLIT> Ba3<SPLIT>
\nNUMFP<SPLIT> 6.25<SPLIT> 24<SPLIT> 103.000<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>103.750<SPLIT> 5.741<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>5.616<SPLIT> 420.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>407.<SPLIT> 1.375M<SPLIT> B+<SPLIT> Ba3<SPLIT>
\nAltice<SPLIT> S.A.<SPLIT>
\nATCNA<SPLIT> 7.75<SPLIT> 22<SPLIT> 103.250<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>104.000<SPLIT> 7.005<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>6.837<SPLIT> 568.<SPLIT>/551.<SPLIT> 2.9MMM<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> B3<SPLIT>
\nATCNA<SPLIT> 7.625<SPLIT> 25<SPLIT> 101.875<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>102.375<SPLIT> 7.309<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>7.227<SPLIT> 573.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>565.<SPLIT> 1.48MM<SPLIT> N.A.<SPLIT> B3e<SPLIT>
\n
\n{IMGR<GO>}<SPLIT>
\n    "
"  Amt<SPLIT>
```

Now I want to parse the text, so that are no quotes, no \n, no whitespace at the beginning and no empty lines.

I have used this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("rawtext.txt"),',', '"', 1);
          String csv = "ParsedRawText.txt";
          CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv),CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

          //Read all rows at once
          List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();

          for(String[] output : allRows) {
             //get current row
             String[] parsedRow=new String[output.length];
             for(int i=0;i<output.length;i++){

                 parsedRow[i]=output[i].replaceAll("(?m)^n", "").trim();

                 System.out.println(parsedRow[i]);
             }

             //write line
             writer.writeNext(parsedRow);
         }
         writer.close();

    }
```

And my outcome is:

```
Amt<SPLIT>
Security<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> Px<SPLIT> A<SPLIT> Px<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> YTW<SPLIT> A<SPLIT> YTW<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> ZS<SPLIT> A<SPLIT> ZS<SPLIT> Out<SPLIT> S&am<SPLIT> Mood<SPLIT> Note<SPLIT>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------<SPLIT> 
Altice<SPLIT> France<SPLIT>
NUMFP<SPLIT> 4.875<SPLIT> 19<SPLIT> 99.875<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>100.375<SPLIT> 4.909<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>4.752<SPLIT> 371.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>371.<SPLIT> 2.4MMM<SPLIT> B+<SPLIT> Ba3<SPLIT>
NUMFP<SPLIT> 6<SPLIT> 22<SPLIT> 102.000<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>102.500<SPLIT> 5.559<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>5.450<SPLIT> 422.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>411.<SPLIT> 4MMM<SPLIT> B+<SPLIT> Ba3<SPLIT>
NUMFP<SPLIT> 6.25<SPLIT> 24<SPLIT> 103.000<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>103.750<SPLIT> 5.741<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>5.616<SPLIT> 420.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>407.<SPLIT> 1.375M<SPLIT> B+<SPLIT> Ba3<SPLIT>
Altice<SPLIT> S.A.<SPLIT>
ATCNA<SPLIT> 7.75<SPLIT> 22<SPLIT> 103.250<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>104.000<SPLIT> 7.005<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>6.837<SPLIT> 568.<SPLIT>/551.<SPLIT> 2.9MMM<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> B3<SPLIT>
ATCNA<SPLIT> 7.625<SPLIT> 25<SPLIT> 101.875<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>102.375<SPLIT> 7.309<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>7.227<SPLIT> 573.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>565.<SPLIT> 1.48MM<SPLIT> N.A.<SPLIT> B3e<SPLIT>

{IMGR<GO>}<SPLIT>
Amt<SPLIT>
```

So the only thing **not working is the empty line in the third last row**.
Does someone has an idea how to solve this?

Desired outcome:

```
    Amt<SPLIT>
    Security<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> Px<SPLIT> A<SPLIT> Px<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> YTW<SPLIT> A<SPLIT> YTW<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> ZS<SPLIT> A<SPLIT> ZS<SPLIT> Out<SPLIT> S&am<SPLIT> Mood<SPLIT> Note<SPLIT>
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------<SPLIT> 
    Altice<SPLIT> France<SPLIT>
    NUMFP<SPLIT> 4.875<SPLIT> 19<SPLIT> 99.875<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>100.375<SPLIT> 4.909<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>4.752<SPLIT> 371.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>371.<SPLIT> 2.4MMM<SPLIT> B+<SPLIT> Ba3<SPLIT>
    NUMFP<SPLIT> 6<SPLIT> 22<SPLIT> 102.000<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>102.500<SPLIT> 5.559<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>5.450<SPLIT> 422.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>411.<SPLIT> 4MMM<SPLIT> B+<SPLIT> Ba3<SPLIT>
    NUMFP<SPLIT> 6.25<SPLIT> 24<SPLIT> 103.000<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>103.750<SPLIT> 5.741<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>5.616<SPLIT> 420.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>407.<SPLIT> 1.375M<SPLIT> B+<SPLIT> Ba3<SPLIT>
    Altice<SPLIT> S.A.<SPLIT>
    ATCNA<SPLIT> 7.75<SPLIT> 22<SPLIT> 103.250<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>104.000<SPLIT> 7.005<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>6.837<SPLIT> 568.<SPLIT>/551.<SPLIT> 2.9MMM<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> B3<SPLIT>
    ATCNA<SPLIT> 7.625<SPLIT> 25<SPLIT> 101.875<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>102.375<SPLIT> 7.309<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>7.227<SPLIT> 573.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>565.<SPLIT> 1.48MM<SPLIT> N.A.<SPLIT> B3e<SPLIT>
    {IMGR<GO>}<SPLIT>
    Amt<SPLIT>
```

Outcome with Avinash's solution:

```
Amt<SPLIT>
Security<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> Px<SPLIT> A<SPLIT> Px<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> YTW<SPLIT> A<SPLIT> YTW<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> ZS<SPLIT> A<SPLIT> ZS<SPLIT> Out<SPLIT> S&am<SPLIT> Mood<SPLIT> Note<SPLIT>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------<SPLIT> 
Altice<SPLIT> France<SPLIT>
NUMFP<SPLIT> 4.875<SPLIT> 19<SPLIT> 99.875<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>100.375<SPLIT> 4.909<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>4.752<SPLIT> 371.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>371.<SPLIT> 2.4MMM<SPLIT> B+<SPLIT> Ba3<SPLIT>
NUMFP<SPLIT> 6<SPLIT> 22<SPLIT> 102.000<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>102.500<SPLIT> 5.559<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>5.450<SPLIT> 422.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>411.<SPLIT> 4MMM<SPLIT> B+<SPLIT> Ba3<SPLIT>
NUMFP<SPLIT> 6.25<SPLIT> 24<SPLIT> 103.000<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>103.750<SPLIT> 5.741<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>5.616<SPLIT> 420.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>407.<SPLIT> 1.375M<SPLIT> B+<SPLIT> Ba3<SPLIT>
Altice<SPLIT> S.A.<SPLIT>
ATCNA<SPLIT> 7.75<SPLIT> 22<SPLIT> 103.250<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>104.000<SPLIT> 7.005<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>6.837<SPLIT> 568.<SPLIT>/551.<SPLIT> 2.9MMM<SPLIT> B<SPLIT> B3<SPLIT>
ATCNA<SPLIT> 7.625<SPLIT> 25<SPLIT> 101.875<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>102.375<SPLIT> 7.309<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>7.227<SPLIT> 573.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>565.<SPLIT> 1.48MM<SPLIT> N.A.<SPLIT> B3e<SPLIT>n{IMGR<GO>}<SPLIT>
Amt<SPLIT>
```

Comment: Yes, but as you can see on the end of the second line, it added again an "n" so there is a n{IMGR<GO>}<SPLIT>. But before the small n there should be a new line with only {IMGR<GO>}<SPLIT> and afterwards in the next line (which is already correct) the Amt<SPLIT>

Comment: I put the desired outcome in the question

Comment: try `output[i].replaceAll("(?m)^n", "").replaceAll("(?m)([\\r\\n])[\\r\\n]+|^ +| +$", "$1")`

Comment: Yeah that it is! Just need to add the .trim() at the end! - Will you update your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another `replaceAll` function.

```
parsedRow[i]=output[i].replaceAll("(?m)^n", "").replaceAll("[\\r\\n][\\r\\n]+", "\\n").trim();
```

**OR**

```
parsedRow[i] = output[i].replaceAll("(?m)^n", "").replaceAll("(?m)([\\r\\n])[\\r\\n]+|^ +| +$", "$1");
```

Comment: I am almost there, now I get the following: ATCNA<SPLIT> 7.625<SPLIT> 25<SPLIT> 101.875<SPLIT>-<SPLIT>102.375<SPLIT> 7.309<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>7.227<SPLIT> 573.<SPLIT>/<SPLIT>565.<SPLIT> 1.48MM<SPLIT> N.A.<SPLIT> B3e<SPLIT>n{IMGR<GO>}<SPLIT>
Amt<SPLIT> - Meaning that n{IMGR<GO>} now is on the same line with with the last one (I will update it in my question

Comment: sorry i can't get your results. Could you explain a bit?

Comment: I updated the outcome with your solution. On the second last line, there should be a line break before the n{IMGR<GO>}<SPLIT>